# Button not identified in Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to click on a button which is very much visible on the screen but selenium webdriver throws this error

```
[Parser] Running:
  C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\testng-eclipse\testng-customsuite.xml

FAILED: Myclass
org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out after 10 seconds waiting for visibility of element located by By.selector: #loginbutton
Build info: version: '2.41.0', revision: '3192d8a', time: '2014-03-27 17:18:15'
System info: host: 'MININT-K353O1P', ip: '192.168.1.5', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_51'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.timeoutException(FluentWait.java:259)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:228)
    at test.test.testEmailGenerator(test.java:33)
... Removed 22 stack frames

===============================================
    test.test
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================


===============================================
test
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================

[org.testng.internal.PoolService] Shutting down poolservice org.testng.internal.PoolService@95e522c terminated:false
```

The button I'm trying to verify has html tags as follows:

```
<input id="loginbutton" type="submit" name="loginbutton" value="" onclick="clkLgn()" style="width: 59px; height: 20px"></input>
```

My basic code so far:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
             WebElement BTN = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("#loginbutton")));

             BTN.sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);
```

Comment: Is the button contained in a `frame` or `iframe`?

Answer (score 0):

So here is the solution for my question above. I clicked the button using the Javascript a

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jse.executeScript("document.getElementById('loginbutton').click();");
```